# Problem with "pycountry.db" --- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'db'

Tags: python, reddit

### edit: Turns out it was some kind of compatibility issue with reddit and the newest (0.14) version of pycountry. easy_install'd 0.12.1 and everything's working now

I'm trying to setup a reddit instance and ran into this error

here's the stacktrace

```
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-py2.6.egg/pylons/error.py', line 245 in respond
  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 302 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 427 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 371 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 386 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 107 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 107 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 107 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 500 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 523 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, custom_start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-py2.6.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 314 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 152 in __call__
  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Routes-1.8-py2.6.egg/routes/middleware.py', line 99 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-py2.6.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 94 in __call__
  controller = self.resolve(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-py2.6.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 170 in resolve
  return self.find_controller(controller)
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py', line 534 in find_controller
  __import__(self.package_name + '.controllers')
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/__init__.py', line 22 in <module>
  from listingcontroller import ListingController
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/listingcontroller.py', line 22 in <module>
  from reddit_base import RedditController, base_listing, organic_pos
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/controllers/reddit_base.py', line 28 in <module>
  from r2.lib import pages, utils, filters, amqp
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/pages/__init__.py', line 22 in <module>
  from pages import *
File '/home/reddit/reddit/r2/r2/lib/pages/pages.py', line 55 in <module>
  import graph, pycountry, time
File '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycountry-0.14-py2.6.egg/pycountry/__init__.py', line 16 in <module>
  class Countries(pycountry.db.Database):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'db'
```

line 16 `class Countries(pycountry.db.Database):` is preceded by `import pycountry.db` a few lines above, so if "pycountry.db.Database" threw an error about module object has no attribute db, shouldn't the `import` line throw an error as well? What can I do?

Comment: Do you have another file called `pycountry.py` in your local directory, by any chance?

Comment: no, turns out it was a compatibility issue with reddit and pycountry 0.14.  thanks for your help though :)